# i am trying to add bootsrap into my html, but as soon as i enter the link my separate css stopped working?

Tags: html, css

I am designing a fitness website, for testimonials, I tried using bootstrap code. but as soon as I enter the link for bootstrap CSS my own CSS stopped working.

first, I gave the link to bootstrap file than on second line gave the link of my own CSS file but still not working

```
<html><head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<title>NewliFit</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.theme.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/firstone.css">



<script src="javascript/fade.js"></script>

</head>
```

.

Comment: Can you give an example of the css in your stylesheet that stops working?

Comment: firstone.css is not working, but as soon as I delete the link of bootstrap.min.css everything works fine,

Answer (score 0):

That’s weird, I know that you must add a link to Bootstrap before you add your own files, but unless you have a name conflict in your own CSS, everything should work as planned. A strange tip, would be to check that you don’t have uncalled for spacing between your HTML tags. Apart from that you’d need to post your code.
Cheers